# SQL Column value search text to list

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to get status values as a list from a log table using SQL.

Response column: (Full string)
"

```
{"headers":{"date":"Wed, 07 Oct 2020 06:46:33 GMT","server":"RR/1.983","transfer-encoding":"chunked","vary":"Accept-Encoding","x-frame-options":"SAMEORIGIN;","access-control-allow-headers":"Content-Type, Authorization","strict-transport-security":"max-age\u003d63072000","access-control-allow-methods":"GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, PATCH, OPTIONS","access-control-allow-origin":"*","access-control-allow-credentials":"true","x-xss-protection":"1; mode\u003dblock","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","content-type":"application/json;charset\u003dutf-8","cache-control":"no-transform"},

"body":[
    {"index":114,"status":"success","subRequestId":"0051"}},
    {"index":114,"status":"failure","subRequestId":"0052"}},
    {"index":114,"status":"failure","subRequestId":"0053"}},
    
],"status":200}
```

"

I want to get:

```
{"index":114,"status":"failure","subRequestId":"0052"}}
{"index":114,"status":"failure","subRequestId":"0053"}}
```

I tried:

```
select log.RESPONSE
from LOG_TABLE log
where log.RESPONSE like ('%failure%');
```

How can I do this with sql, can you help?

Answer (score 1):

Please specify your db vendor. For case of Postgres, use [Postgres JSON functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-json.html).

Your requested result can be achieved using this query ([db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f097f47bc85a6749a14d583c67f61831)):

```sql
with log (response) as (values('{"headers":{},
"body":[
    {"index":114,"status":"success","subRequestId":"0051"},
    {"index":114,"status":"failure","subRequestId":"0052"},
    {"index":114,"status":"failure","subRequestId":"0053"}
],"status":200}'::json)
)
select x.*
from log, json_array_elements(log.response->'body') as x(v)
where x.v->>'status' like '%failure%'
```

For more complex condition, you might want to break inner json to set using `json_to_recordset` and then assemble to json back.

UPDATE after specifying vendor: then use [Oracle functions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/JSON_TABLE.html#GUID-3C8E63B5-0B94-4E86-A2D3-3D4831B67C62) ([db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=82f563f3baf047072f22a04a7a10038e)):

```sql
with log (response) as (select '{"headers":{},
"body":[
    {"index":114,"status":"success","subRequestId":"0051"},
    {"index":114,"status":"failure","subRequestId":"0052"},
    {"index":114,"status":"failure","subRequestId":"0053"}
],"status":200}' from dual
)
select json_object('index' value "index",'status' value "status",'subRequestId' value "subRequestId")
from log, json_table(response, '$.body[*]' columns (
  "index" number path '$.index',
  "status" varchar2(4000) path '$.status',
  "subRequestId" varchar2(4000) path '$.subRequestId'
)) x
where x."status" like '%failure%'
```

or shorter version equivalent to Postgres dialect above ([db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9afb7b34e013f91a2fce5b74c1a14d2e)):

```sql
select x.*
from log
   , json_table(response, '$.body[*]' columns (
       obj varchar2(4000) format json path '$'
     )) as x
where json_value(x.obj,'$.status') like '%failure%'
```

Note JSON support was added since v.12.

Comment: thank you, i am using oracle 18c

Comment: @netdevnet . . . That information belongs in the question, as a tag, not as a comment.

Comment: @netdevnet I have updated my answer for Oracle.